# Book about a man who crashes on a planet and saves the princess with a magical weapon

Tags: story-identification, books, weapon, soft-sci-fi

Many years ago I bought a very cheap sci-fi/fantasy book. What I remember:

- I think the cover was kind of red.
- A guy/pilot crashed with his spaceship on an unknown planet - in a forest.
- He is hurt, someone saves him. He wakes up in a nice place/palace - meets the princess.
- I think she tells him there is a prophecy about a man coming and saving their people.
- He has to fight (in a labyrinth?) to get a magical weapon - the weapon speaks/whispers to him - I recall it was a sword/spear.
- Then he goes on to save the "native" people of the planet - I can remember their skin color is blue.
- Again it sounds like a popular movie, but the natives have some special animals they ride into battle.
- The hero has black hair/very dark hair and I think a beard.
- I am sure that on the cover you can see this man.

Comment: Welcome to the site. You have a good start here. If you could take a look at this [guide](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to help jog your memory and [edit] in any more details, that would be great. Every little bit helps us.

Comment: I think that was called Luke Dances with Avatars

Comment: haha yeah sounds like avatar but I bought it more than 12 years ago, I think :)

Comment: Except for the part about the talking sword, this rather sounds like something Edgar Rice Burroughs would write. I'm not saying he did -- I'm just saying I wouldn't be surprised if this were a "pulp adventure on an alien planet" type of story by one of the *many* people in the 20th Century who *desperately tried* to imitate Burroughs's approach to storytelling. I've read a fair number of such "pastiches," but I don't think I've read one with a crashed space pilot encountering a *talking* weapon and a *blue-skinned* princess. (Was the princess one of the blue race? You seem to imply that.)

Comment: Hey, the princess was not blue skinned. I think its as you say...one of many random authors who tried to imitate another or become popular with a already popular story. Anyway - I loved that book and have very good memories about the time I was reading it, that`s why I wanted to find it.

Comment: @Icantremember You said the princess tells him about a prophecy that someone will come and save the people. Then you said he saves the blue-skinned native people. It sure sounded like you meant the princess was one of those blue people he was supposed to save! If she wasn't blue, do you remember what color she was? Just how many races did he end up saving?

Comment: the blue people were some kind of native tribe at the coast. I am not sure if they were the same as the princess, but I think they were different. and the strange thing is I cant remember the bad guys at all ;(

Answer (score 4):

This reminds me of *[The Cyborg and the Sorcerers](http://www.watt-evans.com/thecyborgandthesorcerers.shtml)*, one of Lawrence Watt-Evans first novels, if not the first.  The titular cyborg is a warrior who fights on long after the war has ended, because no one still alive can decommission him.  In the first chapter, he lands/crashes on a planet where his ship has detected "gravitational anomalies" -- which turn out to be sorcerers, flying by magic.  He's injured in landing, and rescued and magically healed -- and then the real adventure begins.

Excerpt from the first chapter:

> He lay back on the acceleration couch and wondered idly whether he had been officially decommissioned, and whether anybody left alive had the authority to decommission him. He had no idea, and there was no way he could find out. He had been under total communications silence when the D-series destroyed Old Earth's military -- and probably its civilization as well -- and since then, of course, there had been no signal at all from his home base on Mars. There could be little doubt that his superiors were all long dead; if the war hadn't killed them, the passage of time would have. The fourteen years of subjective time he had spent in space worked out to about three hundred years of outside time, and he doubted very much that anyone on Old Earth had been making breakthroughs in geriatrics after the war was lost.

[image: The Cyborg and the Sorcerers front cover]

Comment: as I remember the books starts with the crash and he is not a cyborg.

Comment: All the information about the war and decommissioning is in the first couple paragraphs of the book, and his landing attempt is in the first chapter.

Comment: @Icantremember - Clearly, any comment you make stariting with "As I remember" should probably be taken with a grain of salt. :-)

Comment: well sorry I am just trying to find a book that I bought more than 12 years ago.

Comment: @Icantremember - Sorry if you misunderstood; my comment was making reference to your name on the site. "As I remember" vs. "I can't remember"....